# Why change the keyboard type "decimal pad " from application to another?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

When you choose Keyboard Type, sometimes appear as in Figure 1 and another as in Figure 2 ,,,
  What is the reason?

Figure 1 :-

[image]
Figure 2 :-

[image]
I want as in the first form all my applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in addition to tomsterritt answer, decimal pad can differ between the device languagem for example in a english keyboard the decimal will be a point "." , while in a brazilian portuguese keyboard the decimal will be ",".

try changing languages and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The examples you've added are from different versions of iOS - the system style of the decimalPad keyboard type has changed over time.

If you want a non-system keyboard style you can implement your own. Your desired style should not be too difficult as it has a fairly basic layout & functionality.